# npm init not working while creating new project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm creating a new project using npm init. But while running the command 'npm init -y', I get the error shown below.
[image]

Any solutions as to what might be the issue.

Comment: Which version of `nodejs` are you running?

Comment: Have you installed node and npm correctly? Can you add the versions of npm and node?

Comment: @FelixOrinda version 14

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Yes, I have created many project using node before, this is a recent error, current version is 14

Comment: Why don't you create a package.json for the moment and install the dependencies?  The issue seems to be the issue with npm-cli packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had that once, delete the node modules folder and try `npm i` once again

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
```

Comment: There is no node_modules folder. It is a new project.Error occurs when i run npm init command

Comment: You can reinstall node and npm or upgrade them